# Passing function 'a' to function 'b' and needing an argument list for 'a'.

Tags: c++, stl

As an exercise from 'Accelerated C++', I'm reimplementing some of the basic STL algorithms found in the algorithm header. I would like to know why, in some cases, we need to include the parameter list of the function we're passing to another function while some other times, we just need to include the function name. I don't see the logic behind this.

Example:

```
// In this case, I just need to include the 'function' name in the parameter list.
template <class In, class Out, class T>
Out transform(In begin, In end, Out dest, T function) {
    while (begin != end) {
        *dest++ = function(*begin++);        
    }

    return dest;
}

// In this case, 'predicate' requires a parameter list.
template <class In, class Out>
Out remove_copy_if(In begin, In end, Out dest, bool predicate(double x)) {
    while (begin != end) {
        if (!predicate(*begin)) {
            *dest++ = *begin;
        }

        ++begin;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Does it have something to do with the function's return type being template?
Any clarifications would be appreciated!

Comment: note you should use `bool predicate(In::value_type)` here. The iterators doesn't have to point to a double type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the first instance, `function`'s type is templatized. In essence, `T` *does* have the return type and parameter list as part of its type. But since it's a templated type you don't explicitly say it (instead, the compiler deduces it from the calling code).

In the second instance, `predicate` is *not* templatized. Its type is explicitly stated. It would have been possible to templatize it, but for whatever reason that was not done.

Answer (score 1):

The first example function will work with every function or functor (function object [class with overloaded `operator()`]) that

- has a return type convertible to the type of `*dest` and
- a parameter to which `*begin` can be converted.

The second functions will only work if you pass in a function, returning `bool`, taking a `double` argument.

So the first one is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

The first case transforms all of the elements from `begin` to `end`. The second case copies only the ones for which `predicate()` does not return True for that element. Thus, `predicate()` has to have the element passed to it so that it can decide if it should return True or False.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you have a very concrete predicate type, i.e., a function taking a `double` and returning a `bool` instead of an arbitrary function object being callable with a `double` and returning a `bool`. Since you don't try to deduce the type of the function object, you need to specify the type!

In the first case you ask the compiler to deduce the function object type which it happily does.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, all you know about `function` is that it has type `T`, which can be instantiated with anything that supports an `operator ()`, in such a way that the fourth line of your template typechecks (after you have instantiated `In` and `Out` too).  `T` could be a function type but it doesn't need to.

In the second case, `predicate` is a function that takes a `double` and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class predicate
{
int i;
 public:
predicate() {}; 
bool operator()(int x){ return x > 6;};

};

template <class In, class Out>
Out remove_copy_if(In begin, In end, Out dest, predicate& pred) {
while (begin != end) {      
    if (!pred(*begin)) {
        *dest++ = *begin;
        }
    ++begin;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main() {

vector <int> v1, v2(10);
vector <int>::iterator Iter1, Iter2, new_end;

int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++ )
  v1.push_back( i );

int ii;
for ( ii = 0 ; ii <= 3 ; ii++ )
   v1.push_back( 7 );

random_shuffle ( v1.begin( ), v1.end( ) );
cout << "The original vector v1 is:      ( " ;
for ( Iter1 = v1.begin( ) ; Iter1 != v1.end( ) ; Iter1++ )
   cout << *Iter1 << " ";
cout << ")." << endl;
predicate p;
// Remove elements with a value greater than 6
new_end = remove_copy_if ( v1.begin( ), v1.end( ), 
   v2.begin( ), p );

cout << "After the appliation of remove_copy_if to v1,\n "
     << "vector v1 is left unchanged as ( " ;
for ( Iter1 = v1.begin( ) ; Iter1 != v1.end( ) ; Iter1++ )
   cout << *Iter1 << " ";
cout << ")." << endl;

cout << "Vector v2 is a copy of v1 with values greater "
     << "than 6 removed:\n ( " ;
for ( Iter2 = v2.begin( ) ; Iter2 != new_end ; Iter2++ )
       cout << *Iter2 << " ";
   cout << ")." << endl;
}
```

It was suggested that this problem could be solved by including the predicate as a template parameter. In the above code this has been solved without adding another template parameter. Made the predicate a functor that returns a bool.